# How to Log Events generated by pressing the Buttons?

Tags: android, events, button, logging

I have a **activity** which contain various **buttons** like **delete,submit,back,cancel,ok**.
How i need to **log the event** when these **buttons** are pressed like **Number of times the delete button** is **pressed** in a **particular** **activity** etc.How I need to do this Please give any suggestions....

Thank You in Advance:)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final TAG = "ClickCount";
        private int deleteButtonPressCount = 0;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
            findViewById(R.id.button_delete).setOnClickListener(v -> logCount());

        }

        private void logCount(){
           Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(++i));
        }
    }
```

I add a code block to store in sharedpreferences.

```
private void increaseDeleteButtonPressCount(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = this.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("button_count", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int count = preferences.getInt("delete_button_count", 0);
    preferences.edit().putInt("delete_button_count", ++count).apply();
}
```

Comment: can we use deleteButtoncount in a different class  than in  mainactivity class?

Comment: if you using delete button more than one activity, you can use shared preferences to store it or you can define it as static. If you can explain the case more specifically i can help you more.

Comment: i have used delete button in one activity panel as mdelete ,then in another as delete button in such case what i need to do?

Comment: You can access shared preferences everywhere in app with a context and you can get and set count like above code.

Comment: @toffer can we use switch statement to log the events generated by various  buttons & is it necessary to call (on click) function to log the event ?

Comment: Like @Adrián García Campos told you can use fabric answers for detailed log. You should send answer to fabric in every method which triggered by click. Fabric is a very useful tool. You can take a look from here https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

2 options come to my mind:

1. First one is extending the Button class, overriding the onclick method and log there the info you need.
2. Use [Fabric's Answers](http://fabric.io). This lets you track user's events and you can always check it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can store clicked count in various ways after overriding onclick events

1.Store clicked count in SharedPreferences and update it everytime when you clicked that button.
 2.Store in static variable and increment it everytime.

Answer (score 0):

To log the event of the button first you need to set a onClickListener that listens for clicks on a specific button and executes when that button is pressed.

```
Button button = findViewById(...);
buttons.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Do stuff
        }
    });
```

To log the amount of times a button is clicked, create a counter variable and increment it inside the onClick so it executes every time the button is pressed.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html